# How can I poll FTP location to trigger the changes in it?

Tags: java, ftp, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to poll the ftp location.
I'm using Jenkins for continuous integration of the projects.So, it would be helpful if anyone can suggest me with a plugin in Jenkins or any other method to watch over the changes in FTP location. 
I need to monitor the changes in FTP location and as the changes are found I have to build another job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you can achieve this in Jenkins. If I were to just answer monitoring the FTP location part here is how you can do this.

Determine what programming language you want to use. (Java, .NET etc). Write code to 
monitor the FTP server (assuming it is a specific remote directory you want to monitor) 
and execute the job that needs to be executed. Both the monitoring and the executing the
job needs to be done in the programming language.

I am also assuming that you need a timer of some sort to do the monitoring, this can 
also be done using a programming language such as Java.

Comment: I'm trying to write a Java program for this process. But,can't we find any libraries to do this.

Comment: Consider using JSCAPE's [Secure FTP Factory](http://www.jscape.com/products/components/java/secure-ftp-factory/). Documentation can be found [here](http://files.jscape.com/sftp/docs/html/).

Answer (score 6):

Not sure how to do it with Jenkins, but if you want to monitor an FTP location for changes (i.e. receive notifications when files added/removed/modified in a directory) using plain java, then the following library can help you with the actual polling/notification mechanism: https://github.com/drapostolos/rdp4j  (**Remote Directory Poller for Java**).

Simple usage example of the API:

```
package example

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import com.github.drapostolos.rdp4j.DirectoryPoller;
import com.github.drapostolos.rdp4j.spi.PolledDirectory;

public class FtpExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String host = "ftp.mozilla.org";
        String workingDirectory = "pub/addons";
        String username = "anonymous";
        String password = "anonymous";
        PolledDirectory polledDirectory = new FtpDirectory(host, workingDirectory, username, password);

        DirectoryPoller dp = DirectoryPoller.newBuilder()
        .addPolledDirectory(polledDirectory)
        .addListener(new MyListener())
        .setPollingInterval(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .start();

        TimeUnit.HOURS.sleep(2);

        dp.stop();
    }
}
```

The RDP4J [User Guide](https://github.com/drapostolos/rdp4j/wiki/User-Guide):

- provides an example of `FtpDirectory` class which lists files in an FTP location using appache commons `FTPClient`
- describes what events `MyListener` can listen for
- How to configure the `DirectoryPoller`